# How to add a `resolveType` to GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql

I am trying to query a single MongoDB document (`trivia`) using GraphQL, but am having trouble with one of the document fields. It's the `trivia.rounds` field that should return an array of objects (either `LightningRound` or `MultipleChoiceRound`).

`schema.graphql`

```
type Trivia {
  _id: String!
  createdAt: String!
  rounds: [Round]!
}

interface Round {
  type: String!
  theme: String!
  pointValue: Int!
}

type LightningRound implements Round {
  type: String!
  theme: String!
  pointValue: Int!
  questions: [LightningRoundQuestion]
}

type MultipleChoiceRound implements Round {
  type: String!
  theme: String!
  pointValue: Int!
  questions: [MultipleChoiceRoundQuestion]
}

// ...
```

`trivia.js // resolver`

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

const trivia = (app) => {
  return async (root, { _id }) => {
    return app
      .get('db')
      .collection(process.env.DB_COLLECTION_TRIVIA)
      .findOne(ObjectId(_id))
  }
}

module.exports = {
  trivia
}
```

`graphql query`

```
query {
  trivia(_id: "5e827a4e1c9d4400009fea32") {
    _id
    createdAt
    rounds {
      __typename
      ... on MultipleChoiceRound {
        type
        theme
        }
            ... on PictureRound {
        type
        theme
        }
            ... on LightningRound {
        type
        theme
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
"message": "Abstract type \"Round\" must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field \"Trivia.rounds\" with value { questions: [[Object], [Object]] }, received \"undefined\". Either the \"Round\" type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."
```

I don't understand what it means by `resolveType` or `isTypeOf`. I've seen this in other questions, but have no clue what to implement in my setup. The db connection and resolver works fine if I remove the `rounds` field, so it's something there...

Comment: resolver for `trivia` returns an object (from db) but it doesn't contain `rounds` property ... and no resolver to return value (array of objects) for this

Comment: @xadm The object returned from `trivia` does have the `rounds` array with the rounds in them.

Comment: @xadm thanks for the tip. I'm coming at this completely new, trying to wrap my head around GraphQL. I tried union stuff, didn't quite work. I just don't know how to do it. Oh well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GraphQL supports two kinds of abstract types -- unions and interfaces. An abstract type is a type that represents two or more *possible* types. Abstract types allow you to specify a single type for your field that could be one of several possible types at runtime (i.e. when the query is executed). When executing a query, GraphQL can never return an abstract type -- instead, the type has to be *resolved* into one of the possible types when the query is executed.

If a field returns a list, then the type for each item in the list will resolved separately. This type resolution happens *before* any of the fields on each item are resolved. More to the point, the type that's resolved determines which fields need to be resolved in the first place.

In your example above, you've defined an abstract type (the interface `Round`) and several possible types for it (`LightningRound`, `MultipleChoiceRound`, etc.). **However, you have not told GraphQL how to determine whether a `Round` is a `LightningRound`, a `MultipleChoiceRound` or another possible type.** This is the purpose of providing a `resolveType` function. You typically define a `resolveType` function for each abstract type in your schema. Assuming you're using `graphql-tools` or `apollo-server`, you provide this function through the same resolver map object you use to define your resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
  Round: {
    __resolveType: (round) => {
      // your code here
    },
  },
}
```

`resolveType` will be passed the Round object (i.e. one of the objects returned by your `rounds` resolver) -- you can use that value to determine what kind of Round it is. Based on your code, I'm guessing you'd use the `type` property to differentiate between the different types. `resolveType` should return a string value with the name of the matched type. So it could be as simple as:

```
const resolvers = {
  Round: {
    __resolveType: (round) => {
      return round.type
    },
  },
}
```

For additional examples, see [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/).

`isTypeOf` is an alternative approach to resolving the type. Instead of defining a `resolveType` function for the abstract type, you can define a `isTypeOf` function for each possible type. This function returns true or false to indicate whether the object it received is in fact the type. There are uses for `isTypeOf`, but it's typically easier to just use `resolveType` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! I really appreciate it. Only thing, I have no idea where to insert or execute the resolver function... I'm using `graphql-tools` and not apollo, if that helps.

Comment: If you're using `makeExecutableSchema`, then you're passing a `resolvers` option to it. That `resolvers` object should look as shown above (or in the docs).

Comment: I'm using `addResolversToSchema`, and the resolver would make it return the string "MultipleChoice" for example, and not actually have any data. I'm so lost. This is too confusing.

Comment: I would use `makeExecutableSchema` as shown in the `graphql-tools` docs [here](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/generate-schema). Then modify the resolvers object to include the `Round.__resolveType` function as I've shown.

Comment: One of the best written answers I've read in a long time.

Comment: Agree, incredible answer. Thanks

Comment: ^^^ correction: incredible [LONG] answer for a simple question that shouldn't even exist because GQL creates more problems than it solves.